# Algorithm to sort users into teams (based on minimum/maximum number for each team)

Tags: algorithm, sorting, math

I am trying to come up with an algorithm for sorting and assigning teams to a fixed number of users. The majority of algorithms that I've found assume the number of groups to divide by; I would like to create a smart system where the groups are assigned automatically (to the best of its ability) and predicted based on the total user count, and the minimum and maximum number of users per group.

Assume the following criteria for each group:

- Minimum of 3 per group
- Maximum of 6 per group
- Smart grouping based on total number of users

Here are some of the possibilities based on the total user count and the minimum/maximum values for each group:

**For 24 members:**

- 4 groups of 5 and 1 group of 4
- 6 groups of 4
- 4 groups of 6

**For 21 members:**

- 3 groups of 6 and 1 group of 3
- 3 groups of 5 and 1 group of 6 (better choice)

**For 10 members:**

- 2 groups of 5 (better choice)
- 2 groups of 3 and 1 group of 4

Although not necessary, the "better choice" for groups would be an equal amount of users per group (e.g. 10 members would be 2 groups of 5), unless impossible (e.g. 21 members) whereby 5+5+5+6 is "more equal" in terms of members per group than 6+6+6+3.

Comment: You'll need a more careful definition of "better". E.g. if the target is 36, what's better? 12 groups of 3, 9 groups of 4, 6 groups of 6?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution in JS for anyone that's interested https://jsfiddle.net/kp8d0w27/6/

The first loop checks whether the total number of attendees can be divided equally. If it can, do that.

The second loop will only run if the total is not equally divisible, and will loop until the remainder (modulo) is greater than the minimum set and less than the maximum.

Finally, I'm using a Lodash function called chunk to split the original array into equal parts.

```js
const minNumber = 3
const maxNumber = 6

let divisible = false
let totalGroups = 0
let perGroup = 0

const attendees = ['chris', 'kevin', 'thomas', 'gio', 'nathan', 'michael', 'elyse', 'sarah', 'jacinthe', 'chloe', 'benoit', 'alex', 'darren', 'john']
const totalAttendees = attendees.length

// Can we divide into equal groups?
for (let divider = maxNumber; minNumber <= divider; divider--) {
  totalGroups = totalAttendees / divider

  if (Number.isInteger(totalGroups)) {
    divisible = true
    perGroup = divider
    break
  }
}

// Nope, so divide teams and make sure their between our min and max
if (!divisible) {
  totalGroups = 0;

  for (let j = maxNumber, remainder = 0; minNumber <= j; j--) {
    remainder = totalAttendees % j

    if (remainder >= minNumber && remainder <= maxNumber) {
      perGroup = j;
      break
    }
  }
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(_.chunk(attendees, perGroup)))
```

Not the cleanest (and there's some situations that I did not account for here, like if the number of attendees is less than the minimum), I'm still refactoring, but it works well and solves my original problem.

Answer (score 0):

With the criterion you've given so far - minimum group size variation - the number of cases is limited.

- If the target is a multiple of 3, 4, or 5, split into equal-sized groups. (We never need groups of size 6.)
- Otherwise the target is either 1 or 2 (mod 3).

  - For the mod 1 case use a single group of 4 with all others being 3.
  - For the mod 2 case use two groups of 4 with all others being 3.

Note for 21 you left out the obvious choice of 7 groups of 3.

With this algorithm:

- 24 - 8 groups of 3
- 21 - 7 groups of 3
- 10 - 2 groups of 3, 1 group of 4 (the 1 (mod 3) case)
- 14 - 2 groups of 3, 2 groups of 4 (the 2 (mod 3) case)

Maybe you are quietly thinking (but not saying) that you'd also like to minimize the number of groups. If that's true, then you need to indicate the relative importance of small number of groups and group size variation.  These two factors require a tradeoff.

Comment: Thanks, please see the solution that I came up with.